# How can I specify loosely typed object literal in typescript definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

We are writing typescript definitions for a library named args-js which parses a querystring and returns the results in an object literal.
eg

```
?name=miriam&age=26
```

will return

```
{
  name: "miriam",
  age: 26
}
```

The return value is an object literal, but we can't declare the property names in advance. Is there an alternative to specifying a return value of `any` type?

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7648) might be of interest to you.

Comment: as long as you don't know the propertys before runtime no.
Definitions are only used by typescript. They aren't compiled and they are nonexistent at runtime.
But you can return {}, to indicate that the function returns an object

Comment: I would go with `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the depth of your object is always 1, you can use the type:

```
{[key: string]: string | boolean | number}
```